# Include content of a URL in html file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, nunjucks

I'm building an app with Node.JS and Express v4.
My template engine is [Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/).

I've rendered a *(widget)* route (using Express): `app.get( '/widget' , routes.widget);`. So I can go to the url `http:localhost:9999/widget` and the widget works and loads well.

Now I want to include the widget into my html file. Do I need to use nunjucks? Maybe with javascript or jQuery?

I mean, I want to include the widget in my index.html file, which is called when I load "/" [localhost:9999].

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has function: [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$( "#result" ).load( "http:localhost:9999/widget" );
```

where "#result" is element where you want to put your widget